# What's the difference between the '\zs' and '\@<=' atoms in Vim regex?

Tags: vimrc, regular-expression, search

This is what I get from the documentation: `\zs` "starts the highlighted part" after matching the preceding *regex*, and `\@<=` "starts the highlighted part" after matching the preceding *atom*. But I don't exactly understand the subtleties of this, so can anyone explain how they differ a bit more in depth?

This is what made me curious: If I run

```
/\_s\zsnnoremap
```

i.e. select `nnoremap` preceded by a space or a start-of-line (i.e. the newline from the preceding line, hence the `\_` preceding the `s`) and then run `gn` to enter Visual Mode and visually select the next match, for some reason *only* the first column (i.e. the first `n` in `nnoremap`) is selected -- despite the fact that the entire `nnoremap` word is highlighted with `:hlsearch` turned on.

However, if I instead run the search

```
/\_s\@<=nnoremap
```

and then try `gn`, the entire `nnoremap` is properly selected. What could be going on here? Did I discover some obscure bug?

Comment: I think its in `:h patterns` but my memory suggests that regexs are composed of atoms, if that helps explain the difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like you indeed found an obscure bug. I have implemented the `gn` textobject back in 2012 for Vim 7.3 something. It basically works in the following way:

1) It searches backwards for the last match of the current regular expression.

2) It searches forward for the next match of the current regular expression.

This should make clear, that the cursor will be on start of the next match, even if it was there already at the start of 1). <del>Finally</del>

<del>3) it searches for the end of the current regular expression. and puts the cursor there.</del>

Now what happens here is that the search for the end of the current match wraps around and moves back to the end of the previous match (because `wrapscan` is already set, after being disabled for 1)). It then sets the Visual marker to the area from start (end of point 2) and the area moved to by the next search item 3).

I'll have a closer look at the problem and will probably submit a patch for Vim later.

**[Update 22.05.2018]** I have written and submitted a [patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/IbWNTwpbkGQ/lXQcd8zWBQAJ) to fix this behaviour.

**[Update2 22.05.2018]**
And the patch has been merged as patch level [8.1.0018](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0018)

**[Update 22.10.2019]**
As of Vim patch [8.1.629](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0629) the third step is not performed anymore. Instead Vim can now determine the end of the match when finding the beginning of the match (Step 2)

Answer (score 9):

Christian has completely addressed the question of buggy behavior of `gn`, but there still are fundamental differences between `\zs` and `\@<=`.  One of these being `\@<=` modifies a preceding atom, while `\zs` is an atom in itself.

Consider:

```
Xnnoremap

\%1cX\zsnnoremap     (regex 1)
\%1cX\@<=nnoremap    (regex 2)
\%2cX\@<=nnoremap    (regex 3)
```

Regex 1 matches, since `\%1c` matches in column 1 and there is an X there.  `\zs` merely causes the primary capture to be restarted at a position after the X.

Regex 2 however does not match, because although `\%1c` matches in the first column, `X\@<=` is zero width as mentioned in the documentation.
`nnoremap` starts at column 2, not 1, and besides, as @user938271 points out is no possible position before column 1.

Regex 3 matches since `nnoremap` starts at column 2, and is preceded by an X.

Comment: I don't think the regex 2 fails because there is nothing to make up the position difference between columns 1 and 2. If that was the issue, removing `nnoremap` from the regex would produce a match; but the regex still fails even without.
I think it fails because `\%1cX\@<=` expresses a position which can't exist. `\%1c` matches the position at column 1, and `X\@<=` asks for a character `X` to match before that. But there can't be any character before the first column. Which is why, even if you replace `X` with a dot (any character), the regex `\%1c.\@<=` still fails.

Answer (score 5):

`\zs` applies to the entire regular expression, and sets the next character to be the first character of the entire match. Anything before the `\zs` will not be included as part of the matching text.

`\@<=`, on the other hand, only affects the atoms directly around it, allowing you to specify that the next atom will only match if it follows the preceding atom. So for example, the regular expression:

```
\vbar.*(foo)@<=bar
```

Will match all the text between two instances of `bar` (including the instances themselves), but only if the second is preceded by `foo`. i.e., it will match:

```
barbazfoobar
```

but not:

```
barbazbazbar
```

Because `\@<=` is localized in this way, you can even use `\@<=` multiple times in a single expression:

```
\vbar.*(foo)@<=bar.*(foo)@<=bar
```

The following will match *three* instances of `bar`, but only if the second two are each preceded by `foo`.

i.e. given the text:

```
barfoobarbazfoobar
barfoobarbazbazbar
barbazbarbazfoobar
```

It will match the first line only.

Comment: But you can exchange the first lookbehind with `\zs`, i.e., this should also work: `\vfoo\zsbar.*(foo)@<=bar`.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Good point. I've edited to make clearer the distinction, and to use examples where `\zs` cannot be substituted in at all.

Comment: So, for my understanding, `\zs` and `\ze` can be replaced with look around regex patterns, and they're more powerful, right? More powerful cause they can be used more than once and can be grouped with `\(\)`. And also because they work like perl's look around regex. Anything mistaken?

Comment: @klaus That sounds about right to me (although I'm no expert). Note that you should use `\zs`/`\ze` when you can, though, because they're faster than look-arounds.

Comment: Understood. And `\zs` and `\ze` are obviously more intuitive. Thanks for the explanations.